# Error en el manifest al borrar linea

Tags: android-manifest

Borre una línea en el manfiest porque había borrado un activity y ahora pasa esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor indica más información del problema,muestra la línea que modificaste,como lo tenías antes y código que sea de ayuda,un saludo.

Comment: Además, muestra el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].